# Can I use Hadoop's distributed cache in standalone mode?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm writing a Java MapReduce program in Hadoop, and every reducer needs to have access to a static XML file (that contains some business logic about applying rules to the value lists). I've decided to store this file in distributed cache and then utilize the distributed cache API to access it (serialize it) within every reducer. I haven't implemented this yet, but the API seems straightforward when it comes to using this functionality in HDFS/distributed mode. However, is it possible to utilize it in pseudo-distributed standalone mode for my testing purposes? How would it work?

Also, is it a bad idea to serialize the file in every reducer? I'm open for suggestions on other ways to distributed "global static data" to reducers.

Thanks!

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210222/distributed-cache. Yes Distributed Cache is designed for the purpose of making some data available to all tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can - it would work the same way it would in a real cluster.

This is a good idea to use the distributed cache if it isn't fixed.  The other alternative is to pack that data into the jar that contains the job's code in that case it wouldn't be as flexible when you have to change the XML (you can still change the jar but that's not a clean way to go about it)

Comment: Thanks Arnon. At what file data size would you say using the distributed cache becomes a bad idea? I'll be storing a file containing roughly 140K lines (20 MB) that would be searched by the mappers and reducers. I'll be loading it (via BufferedReader) into a HashMap in the Mapper's or Reducer's configure() method, so that every map() invocation can lookup an element in it. Is this still a normal use of the distributed cache (or an abuse) ?

Comment: You can just measure your performance - but in my opinion it looks like a reasonable use. If you store the info someplace else (a real distributed cache like memcached, hbase etc.) your IO cost would be higher -  as with hadoop's distributed cache the file is copies just once per machine where in other options each map would read the file over the network.

Comment: I am trying to use DistributedCache in standalone environment. I can add the files and it is not throwing any exception. When I am trying to get the files, it is throwing null. Can you help here ?